# AppCompatEditText not found

Tags: android, android-appcompat

When using `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText` in a layout file I get a `ClassNotFoundException`, even though I have the `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0` Gradle depedency (my `targetSdkVersion` is 22).

Any idea why?

Comment: have you perform gradle sync and then clean and build?

Comment: Are you writing a custom view?

Comment: you can just use "EditTextView" and the AppCompat LayoutInflater will replace it with "AppCompatEditText" in inflation process (this works only in xml)

Comment: @indramurari Yes I have

Comment: @EdGeorge No I'm not

Comment: @MoshErsan If I use an `EditTextView` then my theme's `colorAccent` is not applied on pre-Material devices

Comment: Works for me I am using `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0` and `com.android.support:design:22.2.0` (Android Studio default template for BasicActivity), target SDK is `22`. Have you downloaded the repository? Try and update it via SDK Manager.

Comment: @fiddler it will, because on inflation inside the AppCompatActivity, it will check if the name is equal to `EditText` and it will return a new instance of `AppCompatEditText` instead, which in this case it will apply the accentColor, but as the above comment mentioned, you are using an old version of the library, try to update your sdk and libraries, the latest support version is 24.2.0

Comment: @MoshErsan The thing is that I don't want to upgrade my target SDK (because of issues with some native libraries on Marshmallow), and I believe this is necessary to upgrade the `appcompat` library, right?

Comment: @fiddler you can update compileSdkVersion and keep the targetSdkVersion, ex: `compileSdkVersion 24 & buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"      targetSdkVersion 20`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AppCompatEditText` was introduced with `22.1.0`.

Use:

```
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0
```

I suggest you using the latest stable version:

```
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0
```

It requires `compileSdkVersion 24` (don't confuse it with the targetSdk).

Comment: Perfect. It seems to work with `compileSdkVersino 22` though.